# Changing of IP address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway on a "Local Area Network" , NOT "Wireless Network Connection" using bat file

Tags: networking, batch-file

I want to change the above without going to Network Sharing Center. So i used a batch file. I found this code but it only works for Wireless Network Connection but not for "Local Area Networks". I also tried to **rename** my connections before rerunning the script but it still does not change anything.  The code is below

`set connectionName="Local Area Connection"
set staticIP=192.168.247.2
set subnetMask=255.255.255.0
set defaultGateway=192.168.247.2
netsh interface ip set address %connectionName% static %staticIP% %subnetMask% %defaultGateway% 1`
(the last sentence is in a single line)

I also tried to use a simpler code as shown below

`netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.30.77 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.2`

But in the end both programmers didn't change anything when i check the settings under Ipv4.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Try "netsh interface show interface" and change address of an existing interface name rather than "Local Area Connection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open control panel, all control panel, network connections and rename your ethernet adapter by right clicking and selecting 'rename'.

Delete the old name and add "Local Area Connection" - Press enter.

Run script again.

Comment: Hi, i did what you suggested but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It has to be exact including capitalisation - try eth0 instead and reflect that in the batch script - reboot after renaming too.

Comment: Yup, renaming it as eth0 works. Thanks for the help